# loopedSlider jQuery plugin problem

Tags: jquery, css, http, xhtml, jquery-plugins

Hi i use loopedSlider [link text](http://github.com/nathansearles/loopedSlider/tree/master) and there is html source.

```
<div id="loopedSlider"> <div class="container">
<div class="slides">
  <div><img src="01.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div><img src="02.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div><img src="03.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div><img src="04.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div></div><a href="#" class="previous">previous</a> <a href="#" class="next">next</a><ul class="pagination">
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
```

Is there possible to insert div like this:

```
<div class="slides">
   <div>
     <div class="newdiv">Some text</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If i insert this div "newdiv" inside is not showing?
Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe the nested DIV. Try the following instead:

```
<div class="slides">
  <div>
    <span class="newdiv">Some Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can apply the necessary styles to this span to give it DIV-characteristics:

```
div.slides div span.newdiv { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its work but in your code is bug.
Should be:

```
<span class="newdiv">Some Text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask what is the point of this extra inner div? If it is to provide extra styling, surely this can be achieved with inline elements (e.g. span, em) and CSS.

I have used loopedSlider before with  and

elements inside the containing div for each slide, and it has worked perfectly.